# Method not found - System.Web.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode when deploying to azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, azure

I am developing an MVC3 app for azure which is working fine in my local environment, and the azure emulator.  However, when I deploy it to azure I get the error 'Method not found: 'System.Web.Razor.GeneratorResults System.Web.Razor.RazorTemplateEngine.GenerateCode'.

I have added the deployable dependencies using Visual Studio

I haven't had much success finding answers on line, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a deployment issue.  Somehow, the correct .DLL's are not making it over to Azure.  Make sure that deployable dependencies are the correct ones.

Comment: is there any way to determine which dll isn't getting deployed correctly?  everything looks correct, and likesay, it's running in the emulator

Comment: Can you make sure that .DLL versions match to what you actually reference in the References section?

Answer (score 0):

Try to "bin deploy" it. See if it works. There's great blog [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx) for this.

Answer (score 0):

By default there's no MVC3 related assemblies on azure. If you are using Azure SDK 1.6, you can create a MVC3 web role, it will added all necessary assemblies into your BIN and copied to the azure when deployment.

If you are using SDK earlier than 1.6, you have to manually added them into your references and make sure they are all set to Copy Local = True. The assemblies would be

- System.Web.Helpers
- System.Web.Mvc
- System.Web.Providers
- System.Web.Razor
- System.Web.WebPages
- System.Web.WebPages.Deployment
- System.Web.WebPages.Razor